# My domain purchased form hover.com is showing Hover metadata when sharing on facebook

Tags: html, hover, metadata

I purchased a domain address from hover.com. I'm ready to share my site, however when I share my site the metadata (image, description, title) that displays on Facebook is Hover's title image and description. I have all the proper meta tag in my head of my site. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code the domain is duuer.com

Comment: Did you retry this?   When I put this in facebook it shows:

`duuer.com` (in bold)
`duuer.com`
`http://duuer.com/`

Comment: There is a Facebook share button on the footer of the landing page on duuer.com. When I click that I get hover's info in the Facebook preview

Comment: Interesting, I see that too.  When did you point the domain at your new site?

Comment: About a week ago. I wonder if I'm missing something in my DNS settings.

Comment: Double check the TTL on your domain name?